# Classical Guitar Piece Notation

Tags: classical-guitar

What does the + and .. sign mean on top of the notes?[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is probably an obsolete notation for right-hand fingering, instead of the modern *p,i,m,a,e* notation.

I guess that + means pluck with the thumb, and 1-4 dots mean use the corresponding finger.

A similar (but not identical) notation was used by Mertz in a 19th-century guitar tutor, see https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/442101/torat page 10.

Comment: Yes, this is right. I have quite a few German editions of classical guitar music using this notation.

Comment: Takes me back a long time, it's correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's right-hand fingering shorthand, used more often in the 1800s and early 1900s.

. - I, .. - M, :. - A, + - P

P = Pulgar/Thumb

I = Indice/Index

M = Medio/Middle

A = Anular/Ring

E = Mignolo/4th (pinky)

Comment: You appear to have mixed up the Spanish and Italian names for the fingers: `Spanish:` Pulgar, indice, medio, anular, menique. `Italian:` Pollice, indice, medio, anulare, mignolo. `Letters:` p, i, m, a, [c/e/x](http://rec.music.makers.guitar.jazz.narkive.com/nI1nx3h8/finger-naming-standard-p-i-m-a-c)